# Convex polytope can be triangulated without adding new vertices

Tags: combinatorics

> Convex polytope can be triangulated without adding new vertices

Convex polytope means it's a polytope (i.e., convex hull of finitely many points in $\Bbb R^d$) which is also convex. I belive the above statement is true. I tried to prove this by induction on the number of vertices on the polytope but I can't find some systematic triangulation. Could you help?

Edit : it seems it's safe to just write 'polytope' than 'convex polytope'.

Comment: What does it mean to "triangulate" a polytope if it is in higher than two dimensions?

Comment: @coffeemath I mean a simplicial complex that is homeomorphic to the original polytope.

Comment: Oh I see. [but don't know how to prove...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it by induction over the dimension of the polytope.

Take a fixed vertex $v$, triangulate the faces of the boundary that don't contain that vertex, and for each lower dimension triangle you get you include the cone that also has $v$.

In particular this can be used to split a cube into tetrahedra, which can be hard to do just by imagining at first (well, at least for me).

Comment: I don't understand how you induction on the dimension of the polytope. For the cube case, if I delete one vertex then it's a simplicial complex consists of three 2-simplicies in particular, no more convex set. And how about the compatibility issue when you triangulate?

Comment: each of the faces is convex of 1 dimension lower, so you triangulate them in 1 dimension lower and then use their respective cones to triangulate the high dimension polytope.

Comment: the cone you mean can be obtained by connecting vertices of $v$ with other vertices by adding 1-simplex?

Comment: The cone of $T$ with point $V$ is the one  whose vertices are those of $T$ plus $v$.

Comment: How do you know this actually is a triangulation ? i.e., intersection of two simplicies is again a simplex. I don't think it's immediate. I think it's not also immediate that such triangulation covers the original convex set.

Comment: Yeah you have to write like two paragraphs :( but it's all pretty straightforward, let me know if you struggle with it a lot, intersection of simplices is just the cone of the intersection of the two lower dimensional ones, which consists of two cases (if they lie on the same face or not). And for the problem as to whether it covers you can do double inclusion.

Comment: I found an html page that explains it a bit more https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/projects/tetra/

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4264114/152299) by Yorch, let's start with an example in two dimensions.

Suppose ABCDE is a planar pentagon - a convex 2D polytope. Choose a vertex, for example: A. It belongs to two sides, AB and AE.
Skip those two and consider the remaining three. Each of them is a complex of one dimension less than the initial polytope ABCDE. Also, each of them appears a simplex. So, on each of them we build a cone, or a pyramid (which in 2D become triangles), all with the common apex A.
Those cones appear 2D simplices, we're done: the pentagon is a union of triangles ABC, ACD and ADE.

Let's see a 3D example now.

Suppose ABCDEF is a pentagonal pyramid with apex F. Choose a vertex F.
Now the chosen vertex belongs to all five lateral sides of the figure, so we have the pentagonal base as the only face for further routine.
This, however, is not a 2D simplex – so it must be decomposed. We do it as described above. As a result we get three triangles and then we build three tetrahedrons on them as bases with a common apex F.

Of course we needn't choose F. We can choose D instead.
Then we have three faces to which D belongs: CDF, DEF and the base. We skip them and consider the remaining three: ABF, BCF and EAF. Each of them is a 2D simplex already, so we build three 3D simplices on them with a common apex D – and we get the pyramid decomposed into tetrahedrons.

Similarly in each n-dimensional space we choose one vertex, recursively decompose (n-1)-dimensional faces into simplices and build n-dimensional cone (simplex) on each, using the initially chosen vertex as their common apex.